# How to bring an application minimized to tray after Explorer crash?

Tags: windows-xp

FastCopy was in the process of copying a large amount of data, while minimized to tray (so it doesn't get in the way). Then Windows Explorer crashed, and now FastCopy is no longer in the Task Manager's Applications tab but only in the Processes tab.

Is there any way to "get it back" without killing it as a process and starting it again? Since  the copy operation it is doing is halfway through (around 25h time out of estimated 43h total).

All ideas welcomed (regardless of whether they actually work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Search for the process, open the context menu and pick **Window** → **Restore**

[image]

This will only work if there's still a window associated with the process.

Comment: Although I managed to figure it out, ProcessExplorer was indeed the way to go. Thanks mate!